# Multiplying a np.int8 array with 127 yields different numpy array types depending on platform

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The following code:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(2).astype(np.int8) * 127
```

produces for numpy 1.13.3

```
# On Windows
array([0, 127], dtype=int16)
# On Linux
array([0, 127], dtype=int8)
```

However, if I change the `127` to a `126`, both return a `np.int8` array. And if I change the `127` to a `128` both return a `np.int16` array.

**Questions:**

- Is this expected behaviour?
- Why is it different for the two platforms for this one case?

Comment: That sounds like a bug. It should be np.int8 on Windows.

Comment: Somehow, `numpy.can_cast(127, numpy.int8, casting='safe')` returns `False` on Windows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is due to [NumPy issue 5917](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5917). A [`<` instead of `<=`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.3/numpy/core/src/multiarray/convert_datatype.c#L1356) caused `np.can_cast(127, np.int8)` to be False, so NumPy used a too-large dtype for 127. The OS-dependence is because C longs have a different size on Linux and Windows, and some NumPy code paths depend on the size of a C long.

A [fix](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/9778) has been released in [NumPy 1.14.0](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/doc/changelog/1.14.0-changelog.rst). Once you update to at least NumPy 1.14.0, you should see a dtype of `int8` on all platforms.